# How to use global variables in django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I use django_rest_framework. I need parse huge xml file then find some data.

Parse xml on get call is bad idea because is too long time. I try once a 3 minute parse it and save parsed object to global variable. But I'm not sure about it work correctly.

Example:

```
class MyView(APIView):

    catalog = None
    parse_time = 0

    @classmethod
    def get_respect_catalog(cls):
        if time.time() - cls.parse_time > 300:
            cls.catalog = parse_xml()
            cls.parse_time = time.time()
        return cls.catalog 

    def get(self, request):
        vals = catalog.xpath('tag/text()')  # here i find some tag
        ...
        return response
```

I sent several requests but many time variable parse_time had value 0. As if class MyView recreate sometimes and class variables "catalog" and "parse_method" resets to init values.

I  think it because uwsgi have many workers and many interprets. May be exists way for using global variables in django.

P.S. I know for my case I need use database. But I want use global vars.

Comment: Please *don't*. Global variables make a webserver unpredictable, and often will result in bugs that are hard to understand.

Comment: You can work with rabbitmq and process a task with such queueing mechanism.

Comment: You are right, there are several uwsgi workers resulting in multiple instances of django. The only way to share something globally is using a database of another service. You can write the value in a database, or you could use a message broker as suggested by @WillemVanOnsem, which would be the cleaner solution.